# STI + namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, model, sti

I need to be able to schedule reminders for users. So I thought I could just create a base model `Reminder` and use STI to make descendant classes which override the function `fire()`, called when reminder fires. But different user roles have similar types of reminders. So they need to be namespaced, e.g. `Adult::BrushTeethReminder` sends an email to user, `Kid::BrushTeethReminder` posts on kid's FB wall.

Is it possible with STI and how if yes?
Other way I see is to just prefix model names like `KidBrushTeethReminder`. Or go even deeper - write a factory method which creates objects according to type. Or is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you do can use STI for models in different namespaces. You just need to place them in appropriate subfolders. For example, `Kid::BrushTeethReminder` should be placed under `app/models/kid` in file `brush_teeth_reminder.rb`

Answer (score 1):

I see two types of reminders, one for adult and one for kid. Personally, I would use an STI called Reminder and have one model called BrushTeeth inherit from Reminder. In the BrushTeeth model, I would have two Boolean columns named for_adult and for_kid.

In your Namespace for Adult, you can check BrushTeeth by querying whether the for_adult column is set to TRUE and base your logic / implementation from there. And for the Kid Namespace, you check the for_kid column.

Having Reminder as the base, gives you the option to have other reminders easily (i.e. Shower, Bath, Nails, etc). The Reminder model also comes with a Type column, since this is an STI model.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was actually intending to use `Reminder` as base class. But Kid and Adult are just a simple example, indeed there's a lot of different roles and reminders, so adding columns `for_kid`, `for_adult` won't be an elegant way.